# Multiple build/compilation errors in Node Modules after installation of angular-material --

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, angular8, angular-cdk

My project is in Angular 8.
I installed angular material to it. And now while I am trying to launch my app, I am getting the following bunch of build errors --

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/icon/typings/icon-registry.d.ts:2:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http'.

2 import { Http } from '@angular/http';
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/material/select/typings/select.d.ts:11:10 - error TS2305: Module '"E:/REPRIMX/SellcodesProj_MEAN/ProtikAppCore/CameraApp/node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay"' has no exported member 'ConnectedOverlayDirective'.

11 import { ConnectedOverlayDirective, Overlay, RepositionScrollStrategy, ScrollStrategy, ViewportRuler } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@angular/material/stepper/typings/stepper.d.ts:19:5 - error TS2416: Property '_stepHeader' in type 'MatStepper' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CdkStepper'.
  Type 'QueryList<ElementRef<any>>' is not assignable to type 'QueryList<FocusableOption>'.
    Property 'focus' is missing in type 'ElementRef<any>' but required in type 'FocusableOption'.

19     _stepHeader: QueryList<ElementRef>;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/typings/key-manager/focus-key-manager.d.ts:17:5
    17     focus(origin?: FocusOrigin): void;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'focus' is declared here.
```

My latest version of package.json is as --

```
{
  "name": "camera-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I have this line in my app.module.ts imports section --

```
import { MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatSelectModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material'
```

I consulted some more links and according to them installed rxjs-compat, @angular/cdk as you can see above. But still the error persists.

I don't want a drastic/radical type of approach to resolve this. What's the shortest smartest way to resolve the above and get it up and running again? What more specific packages are required here? Should I include more necessary imports in the app.module line? What is it. Looking for a fast resolution.

Comment: You are using way too old version of material which is most likely causing the issues. The latest stable version is `8.2.3` - try updating it.

Comment: Are you sure you installed `@angular/material` your `package.json` says otherwise.

Comment: `import { Http } from '@angular/http'` Think you've been using an old version of angular and now just updated to angular8?

Comment: @Eldar yep -- see this in my package.json --> "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2" it is there,

Comment: hi @tftd let me carry out a version update then,

Comment: yes, updating to the latest stable solves the problem @tftd thanks a bunch for pointing in the right direction,

Comment: the issue is resolved.